# Why don't I get the result of this Metal kernel

Tags: swift2, xcode7, metal

I am trying to understand how Metal compute shaders work, so I have wrote this code :

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {


    var number:Float!
    var buffer:MTLBuffer!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        let metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
        let library = metalDevice.newDefaultLibrary()!
        let commandQueue = metalDevice.newCommandQueue()
        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.computeCommandEncoder()


        let pointlessFunction = library.newFunctionWithName("pointless")!
        let pipelineState = try! metalDevice.newComputePipelineStateWithFunction(pointlessFunction)
        commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)
        number = 12

        buffer = metalDevice.newBufferWithBytes(&number, length: sizeof(Float), options: MTLResourceOptions.StorageModeShared)
        commandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)


        commandEncoder.endEncoding()

        commandBuffer.commit()
        commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

        let data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: buffer.contents(), length: sizeof(Float), freeWhenDone: false)
        var newResult:Float = 0
        data.getBytes(&newResult, length: sizeof(Float))
        print(newResult)




    }
```

By making a buffer with StorageModeShared, I want changes made to the Metal buffer reflected in my Swift code, but when I populate my `newResult` variable, it looks like the buffer is still the same value than at the beginning (12) while it should be 125 :

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;



kernel void pointless (device float* outData [[ buffer(0) ]]) {

    *outData = 125.0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kernel function doesn't run unless you dispatch it. I think you're assuming if you have a function, then Metal should run it one time, until you say otherwise, but that won't happen. It will instead not run at all. Add this before `endEncoding` and you're good to go!

```
let size = MTLSize(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1)
commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(size, threadsPerThreadgroup: size)
```